# Switch between TableViews

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have an app where I switch from TableView A to TableView B in Swift. At TableView B the user adds input values and then presses 'save' which calculates the result and switches to Table View A to display the results. This works fine but now I want to switch back to TableView B and add input values to TableView B. But, when I get there, the initial values I've set resets to 0. I tried using `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false` in `viewWillAppear`, tried unchecking 'Clear on appearance' in storyboard, but no luck. Any suggestions would be apprecaited.

Comment: Are these two TableViews in same ViewController? How are you handling TableView switching? Adding screenshots and code in your question will help others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want # value at TableViewB to be different from 0, please pass that # value to TableViewB.

For example:

```
    if let vc = Utils.viewController(storyboardId: "WebViewController", storyboardName: "WebView") as? WebViewController {
        vc.name = "Terms and Conditions" // pass #name to B
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```